# When method changed to GET route not working like POST method Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-request

I have a search bar in view:

```
{!! Form::open(['name' => 'myForm', 
                'method' => 'GET', 
                'action' => 'AreaController@search',
                'files' => true, 
                'onsubmit' => "return validateForm()"]) 
!!}
         
    {!! Form::submit('جستجو', ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) !!}
                       
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And in route file, `web.php`:

```
Route::get('area/search/', 'AreaController@search')->name('area.search');
```

`AreaController`:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    return " it is working" ;
}
```

But when I click on the button, the browser is showing a blank page. When I use `POST` method it is working, but if I change to `GET` method, it is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose this is a LaravelCollective form? Not sure your route is hit at all when using `'action'=>'AreaController@search'`. Also, your post is set to accept file uploads `'files'=>true` ... so your method must be POST

Comment: i removed  'files'=>true  and instead of 'action'=>'AreaController@search' used  'route' => ['area.search']  but still not working

Comment: when I changed route from area/search/  to area-search. it worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

For Post Method, you need to add CSRF Token To A Form

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST']) !!}  <--------- Change to POST method
    
{!! Form::token() !!}  <----------- Add this line 


    {!! Form::submit('جستجو', ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) !!}
                       
{!! Form::close() !!}


Route::post('area/search/', 'areacontroller@search')->name('area.search');
```

OR

If you don't want to add CSRF Token To A Form, You can add that to the route file.

Attaching The CSRF Filter To A Route

```
Route::post('profile', array('before' => 'csrf', function()
{
    //
}));
```

For More Details, you can refer to https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html